# multi thread Issue in phonegap ios and android

Tags: javascript, multithreading, cordova

I had created this code to handle threads in PhoneGap, but if I run this code I am getting the following error.

```
Thread 14 WebCore: Database: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = Oxbbadbeef)
```

I am also using another thread which looks like the one which I had pasted above,  suddenly my application crashes and getting the same error message, and I would also like to use the same multi thread code for both android and Ios could someone suggest me a better way to reuse the same code for both android and Ios ?

So what am I missing in this, and How can i fix this ?

Here is my code :

```
function itmerStart()
{
    if (timerId) return

        timerId = setInterval(loadMessageListCron, 20000);

    function loadMessageListCron()
    {
        var userid = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
        if(userid != undefined)
        {
            alert("thread calling..");
            $.ajax("//abc.com/Rest/get_all_messages?UserId="+ userid).done(function(data)
           {
              var i, response;
              $.each(data.messages, function (i, response)
              {
inboxMessageItmerStop();                                                                                         insertMessages(response, i);
inboxMessageItmerStart();
         });
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure if multithreading or javascript has anything to do with your problem. This looks like kernel panic from a bad access. You are probably attempting to send a message to a deallocated object in objective C, or accessing a resource in a thread unsafe manner. Can you post the native code?

Comment: Much like @Lorenzo commented, this doesn't look like a multithreading issue. setIntrval isn't really multithreading in JavaScript. Not sure if cordova implements this, but to gain true multithreading in JavaScript, take a look at [web workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the loadMessageListCron function still running when it is called again. Try below:

```
var delay = (function()
{
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();


function loadMessageListCron()
{
    var userid = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
    if(userid != undefined)
    {
        alert("thread calling..");
        $.ajax("//abc.com/Rest/get_all_messages?UserId="+ userid).done(function(data)
       {
          var i, response;
          $.each(data.messages, function (i, response)
          {
          });
       });
    }
}


setInterval(function(){
  var pause = 1000;
  delay(function() {

    loadMessageListCron();
  }, pause );  
}, 20000);
```